# What if I want two or three or four different Paragraphs to be all seperate colors?

Tags: html, css

**What if I want two or three different Paragraphs to be all seperate styles?**

> Blockquote

Example:

```
< p >This is a sentence.< /p >

< p >This is another sentence.< /p >
```

So, can I choose, lets say, two different style for the two different sentences in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **advanced way** would be to use nth-child or pseudo-selectors in CSS, depending on your requirement.

**Simple way** is to give a class or ID to each paragraph and style accordingly:

HTML:

```
<p class="para-1">This is a sentence.</p>

<p class="para-2">This is another sentence.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.para-1{
  color:red;
 }
.para-2{
  color:blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to be able to make paragraph #1 a certain color and then paragraph #2 a different color. If so, you can achieve this by using classes or id's on the HTML tags and then specify the styles for those individual classes or ids.
You can check out this link for details on how to use an id selector:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp

Comment: No problem! @KaiOh. Do you only have those two paragraphs to show on the page?